# Why the constructor is invoked?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring.
Recently I encountered something weird, I was using @Autowired for Auto Injecting Name, Emotion in Person class(I have a different class for each Name, Emotion, Person).
I encountered that the **Person constructor was getting invoked** even if I have not used @Autowired with it. **Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?**.

**Is it related to the Automatic Invocation of Constructor after Object Creation(Person)?
Also why Constructor is invoked before @Autowired Functions? (As u can see in the output)**

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id = "emotionAngry" class="gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation.Emotion">
        <property name="name" value="Angry :-O"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "nameAnuragSaini" class="gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation.Name">
        <constructor-arg value="Anurag Saini"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "person" class="gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation.Person"/>

</beans>
```

**Emotion.java**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation;

public class Emotion {
    String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("[EMOTION]:Setting Name of Emotion");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emotion{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Name.java**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation;

public class Name {
    String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        System.out.println("[NAME]: Setting Name Bean");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Person {
    Name name;
    Emotion emotion;

    @Autowired
    public void setName(Name name) {
        System.out.println("[PERSON]: Setting Name of Person");
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setEmotion(Emotion emotion) {
        System.out.println("[PERSON]: Setting Emotion of Person");
        this.emotion = emotion;
    }

    public Person(Name name, Emotion emotion) {
        System.out.println("[PERSON]: Constructor Setting Person");
        this.name = name;
        this.emotion = emotion;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", emotion=" + emotion +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Main App.java**

```
package gd.rf.anuragsaini.autowired.annotation;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext IOC = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        Person person1 = IOC.getBean("person", Person.class);//No need of Type Casting when class is specified
        System.out.println(person1);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[EMOTION]:Setting Name of Emotion
[NAME]: Setting Name Bean
[PERSON]: Constructor Setting Person
[PERSON]: Setting Name of Person
[PERSON]: Setting Emotion of Person
Person{name='Name{name='Anurag Saini'}', emotion=Emotion{name='Angry :-O'}}
```

Comment: Which other `Person` constructor do you expect spring to call?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I have not mentioned **autowire="constructor"** in XML configuration of Person bean nor have I used Autowired on the constructor in Person class. So my question is How is it getting invoked? I need an explanation for this?

Comment: So, it should call which other constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a Bean of Person class in your xml file, therefore Spring will create an instance of this class. And the constructor you have defined takes a Name and Emotion both other classes you have an instance of.
So Spring will create a Bean of Person even if you don't use it with `Autowire`.

And it gets invoked before the '@Autowire functions' as you called them because they are methods and you need an instance to call them and the constructor gets called when you create an instance.

I hope I understood your question correct and this answers it.

Comment: Okay u mean Constructor will always be the first to invoke than any other setter method, so if I define a constructor in the Emotion class along with the property setter method and still use the <property> tag in the Emotion bean in config XML File why it gives me error can u explain? Is it that Spring will see that Oh I have the Constructor and will try to run it but then it will see that <property> tag is applied and therefore due to this contradiction it gives error?

Comment: Well that's a different question and I would need some more information e.g. what error you get

Comment: WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emotionAngry' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: So now you have a constructor in Emotion which takes a value for the name. Im not a big fan of XML files to configure the bean and I don't use it myself so I'm not sure here. But when you have a constructor Spring always tries to find a fitting bean to inject. In your case with type 'java.lang.String' as the exceptions says and my guess is that the property you define doesn't count as bean Spring will just use it to set the value and thats it.

Comment: Thank you for the Explanation, as I have understood Spring always tries to run the constructor if is defined in the class, and for the parameters of the constructor Spring will try to find out the same type of bean to pass as a value in the constructor in the IOC Container but since String bean is not defined in IOC Container, it has given us the java.lang.String exception and ultimately program will fail here and it will not try to check that we were trying to make the bean using <property>.